# Retrieving concrete data from String

Tags: java, regex, string

Im trying to retrieve data-product id from the String which goes like this:

```
<a href="/w-pustyni-i-w-puszczy-sienkiewicz-henryk,prod14290034,ksiazka-p" class="img seoImage" title="W pustyni i w puszczy &nbsp;-&nbsp;Sienkiewicz Henryk" rel="nofollow" data-product-id="prod14290034"> <img class="lazy" src="/b/mp/img/svg/no_picture.svg" lazy-img="https://ecsmedia.pl/c/w-pustyni-i-w-puszczy-p-iext43240721.jpg" alt=""> </a>
```

The output should be

```
prod14290034
```

I tried to achieve this with a regular expression, but I'm beginner in it.

Is regular expression good for it? If so, how to do it?

/EDIT
According to Emma's comment.

I've made something like this:

```
String z  = element.toString();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("data-product-id=\"\\s*([^\\s\"]*?)\\s*\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(z);
        System.out.println(matcher.find());
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
```

it returns true, but dont print any value. Why?

Comment: You should show what you have tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) for Java - it is a library for parsing HTML pages. There are a lot of other libraries for different languages, [beautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for python.

EDIT: Here is a snippet for jsoup, you can select any element with a tag, and then get needed attribute with attr method.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(
    "<a href=\"/w-pustyni-i-w-puszczy-sienkiewicz-henryk,prod14290034,ksiazka-p\" " +
        "class=\"img seoImage\" " +
        "title=\"W pustyni i w puszczy &nbsp;-&nbsp;Sienkiewicz Henryk\" " +
        "rel=\"nofollow\" " +
        "data-product-id=\"prod14290034\"> " +
        "<img class=\"lazy\" src=\"/b/mp/img/svg/no_picture.svg\" lazy-img=\"https://ecsmedia.pl/c/w-pustyni-i-w-puszczy-p-iext43240721.jpg\" alt=\"\"> </a>\n"
);

String dataProductId = doc.select("a").first().attr("data-product-id");
```

Comment: Im using jsoup. I need ID from that what I posted. The site looks like this: https://www.empik.com/ksiazki,31,s?q=W pustyni i w puszczy&qtype=basicForm&sort=priceAsc and you cannot see exact ID.

Answer (score 0):

You might use some HTML/XHTML/XML library which could transform your string data into document or at least Element and then you can easily obtain the attribute value from there. But if you want to use regex then you can try this snippet

```
  @Test
  public void productId() {
    String src =
        "<a href=\"/w-pustyni-i-w-puszczy-sienkiewicz-henryk,prod14290034,ksiazka-p\" class=\"img seoImage\" title=\"W pustyni i w puszczy &nbsp;-&nbsp;Sienkiewicz Henryk\" rel=\"nofollow\" data-product-id=\"prod14290034\"> <img class=\"lazy\" src=\"/b/mp/img/svg/no_picture.svg\" lazy-img=\"https://ecsmedia.pl/c/w-pustyni-i-w-puszczy-p-iext43240721.jpg\" alt=\"\"> </a>";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(data-product-id=)\"(p[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)\"");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(src);
    String prodId = null;
    if (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
      prodId = matcher.group(2);
    }
    System.out.println(prodId);
    Assert.assertNotNull(prodId);
    Assert.assertEquals(prodId, "prod14290034");
  }
```

Comment: It wont work as id can looke like this also: `p1923133`

Comment: Edited my answer, to take care of this pattern as well